# Cannot visit hadoop web UI outside of VMbox

Tags: hadoop, centos, virtual-machine

Installed cent os 6.7 and configure hadoop, start name and data nodes, and was able to see the web UI in vm browser, but not able to use windows browswer to visit the web ui by the ip 192.168.184.133:50070, able to use 192.168.184.133:22 to ssh by putty. Any advise on this problem?

```
lizhi@mini3 hadoop]$ netstat -nltp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 192.168.184.133:9000        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4807/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5000/java           
tcp        0      0 192.168.184.133:50070       0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4807/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firewall,

use the following command to disable it:

```
$ /etc/init.d/iptables stop
```